# textFieldShouldEndEditing malfunction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, alert

I implemented this method to send a number of alert views to the user when an unwarranted character, or an already taken username was inputed in the textfields:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let acceptedChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_")

    var isTaken: Bool = false

    for c in usernameTxt.text.utf16 {
        if !acceptedChars.characterIsMember(c) {

            let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "username can only contain uppercase & lowercase letters A-Z,numbers 0-9, or the special character(s) _", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = false
            signSecond.highlighted = true

            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true

        }else {
            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = true
            signSecond.highlighted = false
        }
    }; for b in passwordTxt.text.utf16 {
        if !acceptedChars.characterIsMember(b) {

            let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "password can only contain uppercase & lowercase letters A-Z,numbers 0-9, or the special character(s) _", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = false
            signSecond.highlighted = true

            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true
        }else {
            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = true
            signSecond.highlighted = false
        }
    }; for a in confirmTxt.text.utf16 {
        if !acceptedChars.characterIsMember(a) {

            let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "password confirmation can only contain uppercase & lowercase letters A-Z,numbers 0-9, or the special character(s) _", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = false
            signSecond.highlighted = true
            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true
        }else {
            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = true
            signSecond.highlighted = false
        }
    };

    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            if (objects!.count > 0){
                isTaken = true
                let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "username \(self.usernameTxt.text) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
                myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
                myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            } else {
                println("Username is available. ")
            }
        } else {
            println("error")
        }
    }

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Now when I input an invalid string and tap the next textfield, an alert view shows as accordingly. However the issue happens when i tap back to the original textfield to correct the mistake, the alert view shows once again, which I do not want. As a matter fact, If there is an invalid string within the textfield and i select any button or anywhere else thats interactive on the view, the warnings pop up, even if the cancel button is selected. How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you're class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and remember to set the text field's delegate in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: moving it to the `viewDidLoad` just negated the whole function @Cole

Comment: Normally, I would put `myTextField.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad` Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @Cole The issue has nothing at all to do with setting the delegate. The OP already stated that the delegate method is being called. The problem is that it seems to be called too many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the text field delegate method is called for each text field. But you have written the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method to check every text field.

Modify the delegate method so it only checks the text field you are leaving at the moment. Here's an attempt to update your code accordingly. Note that I don't know Swift so I may have some syntax wrong but it should give you the right idea.

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let acceptedChars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_")

    var isTaken: Bool = false

    for c in textField.text.utf16 {
        if !acceptedChars.characterIsMember(c) {

            let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "field can only contain uppercase & lowercase letters A-Z,numbers 0-9, or the special character(s) _", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = false
            signSecond.highlighted = true

            return false // don't leave since it's invalid

        }else {
            signSecond.userInteractionEnabled = true
            signSecond.highlighted = false
        }
    };

    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: textField.text)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            if (objects!.count > 0){
                isTaken = true
                let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Woah There", subTitle: "username \(textField.text) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "Got It")
                myAlert.alertview.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                myAlert.alertview.circleBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
                myAlert.alertview.labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                myAlert.alertview.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0).CGColor
                myAlert.alertview.viewText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                myAlert.alertview.viewText.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.18, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

                return false; // invalid, don't leave
            } else {
                println("Username is available. ")
            }
        } else {
            println("error")
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

There is not thing about my code above that you need to solve on your own and that is the query to parse. It is currently hardcode to check the value of the "username" value. But it should check the field based on the current text field.

Also note how I changed the delegate method to return `false` when the text field value isn't valid. This prevents the user from leaving an invalid text field.

Comment: no it actually is called for separate textfields and have separate alert messages. check updated question

Comment: Right, that's the problem. You check every text field each time you move focus from any one text field. The delegate method should only check one text field - the one you are leaving.

Comment: so should i do a separate delegate method for each one or?

Comment: returning the textfields false solved the issue for those, however when i send the check for an already existing username, i cannot set it false because it is an `unexpected non-void return value in a void function`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's in a block. Just remove that call to `return`. It's pointless anyway now that I look at it again since the check with Parse.com is done in the background.

Comment: hold on there's an issue. now since returning all the textfields false, it doesn't allow the user to leave that textfield until the input has been corrected (which is all fine since that solves the multiple alert view issue), however if you select the cancel button i have at the top of the screen to just return to the home login/sign up view, the view alerts stack on that screen, which they shouldn't

Comment: You need to call `[self.view endEditing:YES];` (use whatever the Swift syntax for that Objective-C code is) when handling the Cancel button.

Comment: that doesn't work, the alert views still stack on the home screen. I don't think that call totally abolishes the activities on the previous screen, but just end's editing, not the call of the alert views

Comment: how do i cancel the calls of the alerts in the cancel button